# Merge two arrays first one based on value and second one based on key - php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays

First array named "$periods" and second array named "$groupExport" like below.

## First Array - $periods

```
Array
(
    [0] => 201308
    [1] => 201309
    [2] => 201310
)
```

## Second Array - $groupExport

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 111
            [GroupDesc] => Crop Production
            [201308] => 1.5500
            [201309] => 240.4200
            [201310] => 41.2110
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 112
            [GroupDesc] => Animal Production
            [201309] => 3.1800
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 115
            [GroupDesc] => Agriculture, Forestry Support
            [201308] => 234.0400
            [201310] => 343.0200
        )
)
```

I have tried atleast 5-6 different code ideas, it does not yields the below output. I want the output like below, so that I can display the resultset in table format according to the header GroupCode, GroupDesc, 201308, 201309 & 201310. Could anyone help me to resolve this?

## Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 111
            [GroupDesc] => Crop Production
            [201308] => 1.5500
            [201309] => 240.4200
            [201310] => 41.2110
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 112
            [GroupDesc] => Animal Production
            [201308] => 0
            [201309] => 3.1800
            [201310] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 115
            [GroupDesc] => Agriculture, Forestry Support
            [201308] => 234.0400
            [201309] => 0
            [201310] => 343.0200
        )
)
```

Comment: Where's the code that you tried unsuccessfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the `$groupExport` array and on each iteration, loop through the sub-array and check if the each one of the period index exists. If they don't, initialize them with 0.

```
foreach ($groupExport as & $export) {
    foreach ($periods as $period) {
        if (!isset($export[$period])) {
            $export[$period] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `&` before `$export`. It means we're passing the array by reference — it's modifying `$groupExport` on each iteration.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133260)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is working what I am expected. If the periods only need to be in ascending order 201308, 201309, 201310 means, how to modify this working code?

Comment: @Vinayagam I'm not sure why it is necessary but if you want to order by keys use `ksort()`. Adding the line `ksort($export)` as the last line before the end of the outside `foreach` loop should do the trick.

Comment: The benefit to this approach is that it doesn't mutate the original array.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This will mutate the original array. If you want to produce a new array, @AmalMurali's solution is superior.*

Here's an alternate solution that uses some of PHP's built-in functions:

```
$keys = array_fill_keys($periods, 0);
array_walk($groupExport, function (&$item, $key, $keys) {
    $item += $keys;
}, $keys);
```

Here's a [demonstration at IDEOne.com](http://ideone.com/E8puYb).

---

## Explanation

```
$keys = array_fill_keys($periods, 0);
```

This converts your array of periods into a new array where the value from the original array is now the key, and the value is `0`.

```
array_walk($groupExport, function (&$item, $key, $keys) {
    $item += $keys;
}, $keys);
```

We walk over each element of the array `$groupExport`, and apply a function to each member. We pass each array element as a reference to our user defined function, which allows us to manipulate it directly.

Finally, we add `$keys` to `$item` which essentially merges the two arrays while maintaining key associations.

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 111
            [GroupDesc] => Crop Production
            [201308] => 1.55
            [201309] => 240.42
            [201310] => 41.211
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 112
            [GroupDesc] => Animal Production
            [201309] => 3.18
            [201308] => 0
            [201310] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [GroupCode] => 115
            [GroupDesc] => Agriculture, Forestry Support
            [201308] => 234.04
            [201310] => 343.02
            [201309] => 0
        )

)
```

---

- [array_fill_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php)
- [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: This is a pretty awesome answer - I had no idea there was a `array_fill_keys()` and I did not know you could pass additional data into `array_walk()`. Brilliant!